# Raspberry Pi Model B Current Overdraw from 3.3V Pin

Tags: pi-3, dc-motor, current

I am using **RPi3 ModelB V1.2** for a motor control project. I am connecting **Pin1 (3.3V)** for power to a micro dc motor. The current drawn by the motor is approx **~70 mA** whereas the RPi sources mention that the **max current drawn from the board is ~50mA**. Will the motor operation just **heat the board due** to **overdraw of the current** **or** **damage the RPi board** completely?

Comment: The GPIOs are rated at 16mA per pin, 50mA per bank. YOU CAN NOT RUN A MOTOR FROM A GPIO PIN - you will destroy your RPi (and the back EMF will do that if nothing else does). Use the GPIO to switch a transistor, a H-bridge or an optocoupler and use that to control your motor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 50 mA limit is for the GPIO.

The 3V3 pins are not GPIO.

You can draw as much current from the 3V3 pins as is available from the power supply.  If you attempt to draw more current than is available the Pi will reboot.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the info. On that note, can I assume that all gpio on board can draw a total of ~50mA and all gpio loads must draw a sum total of only ~50mA?

Comment: @MahadevHansda The advice I have seen from raspberrypi.org is not more than 16 mA from any one GPIO and not more than 50 mA from all (54) GPIO in total.